# free при условии в функции Си

Tags: c, malloc, free

Вот код:

```
char* newstr(char* str, int n)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    if (len >= n)
    {
        str = str + len - n;
    }

    if (len < n)
    {
        char* s = (char*)malloc(n + 1);
        if (s != 0) memset(s, '\0', n + 1);
        if (s != 0) memset(s, '*', n - len);
        if (s != 0) strcat_s(s, n + 1, str);
        str = s;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Вкратце: если n больше длины строки, то начало новой строки заполняется символом *, а остальное заполняется строкой str. При выполнении этого условия, как видно, выделяется память, которую нужно очистить. Вот вопрос: как её очистить, если выполнилось условие n > len? Как это грамотно реализовать? Или это просто нужно делать условием вне функции: если n > len(2 раз len узнавать не хочется на самом деле), то free()?

UPD:
Я сделал так:

```
printf("%s\n", newstr(stroka, n));
free(newstr(stroka, n));
```

Правильно ли это? И что будет делать free, если по условию память не выделялась? Скорее всего это бред, ведь снова выделится память, а старая не будет стерта, только новая...

Comment: Подумайте, может быть вам для использования этой функции в остальном коде имеет смысл вернуть (в ее дополнительном аргументе) признак, что внутри вызывался malloc?

Answer (score 2):

Назначение указателя в `C` указывать место в памяти. Разыменовав указатель, можно читать и писать память. Дополнительно некоторые указатели служат для управления памятью. Будем их называть владеющими. Владеющий указатель возращается функциями `malloc`, `calloc` или `realloc` и может быть передан в функции `free` и `realloc`. Если указатель не владеющий, то будем его называть невладеющим. Невладеющие указатели могут получены как адрес объекта или элемента массива.

Невладеющие указатели нельзя передавать в функции управления памятью. Владеющий указатель когда-нибудь будет передан в такую функцию: в нормальной программе выделенная память рано или поздно освобождается. Глядя на указатель во время выполнения программы невозможно сказать владеющий он или нет. Поэтому программист должен следовать каким-то правилам, чтобы читая код знать владеет указатель памятью или только ссылается на неё.

Последняя вещь - память, указанную владеющим указателем, можно удалить только один раз. Довольно теории, переходим к практике.

```
char *copy_string(char *s) {
    if (<сложное условие>) {
        return s;
    }
    return malloc(...);
}
```

Функция `copy_string` иногда возвращает переданный ей указатель, иногда новый. Новый указатель - владеющий. Про старый указатель такого сказать нельзя. Если он не владеющий, то у нас проблема:

```
 char *s = <невладеющий указатель>;
 char *s1 = copy_string(s);

 // надо ли удалять s1? Неизвестно.
 free(s1);
```

Если указатель владеющий, то у нас другая проблема:

```
 char *s = <владеющий указатель>;
 char *s1 = copy_string(s);

 // удаляем s1
 free(s1);

 // надо ли удалять s? Неизвестно.
 free(s);
```

Если `s == s1`, то удалять `s` не надо - нельзя удалять одну память два раза. Иначе удалить `s` необходимо, чтобы избежать утечки памяти.

Резюме: или вы чётко знаете что такой-то указатель владеющий, а другой - невладеющий или вам нужна дополнительная информация о том как указатели соотносятся во время исполнения программы.

P.S. Иногда вы можете игнорировать вопросы владения и утечки памяти. Это нормальная практика для маленькой утилиты, которая быстро завершается и за которой "убирает" операционная система.

Answer (score 1):

Условие задачи понятно, но вот то, как Вы это реализуете - не очень. Несколько замечаний по стили, что бы прояснить:

Вместо оператора *if (len < n)* надо написать просто *else* Так гораздо спокойней и понятней.

Вместо операторов

```
 if (s != 0) memset(s, '\0', n + 1);
 if (s != 0) memset(s, '*', n - len);
 if (s != 0) strcat_s(s, n + 1, str);
```

Надо просто написать:

```
 if (s != 0) {
     memset(s, '\0', n + 1);
     memset(s, '*', n - len);
     strcat_s(s, n + 1, str);
}
```

В этих операторах есть явная ошибка. Оба вызова функции *memset()* пишут в одно и то же место - значение указателя *s* ведь между вызовами **не** изменилось.

Ну и последнее. Эти два оператора вместе - нонсенс:

```
printf("%s\n", newstr(stroka, n));
free(newstr(stroka, n));
```

Правильно написать вот так:

```
char *wrk;

wrk = newstr(stroka, n);
printf("%s\n", wrk);
free(wrk);
```

Comment: Откуда известно что вызов `free(wrk)` корректен?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ваша функция *newstr(stroka, n)*  должна проверять, что **выделение** памяти прошло нормально. Тогда и её освобождение пройдёт нормально.

Comment: `wrk` может получить указатель который нельзя отдавать во `free`.

Comment: Ну так и надо это проверить !!! *if(ptr == NULL) { // Обрабатываем ошибку* внутри (!) функции.

Comment: `free(NULL)` работает нормально. В `wrk` может оказаться указатель, который нельзя удалять: `wrk = newstr("very_long_string", 5)`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я повторяю уже в **третий** раз: именно поэтому нужно делать проверку валидности указатели **внутри** функции *newstr(stroka, n)* !

Comment: Так ведь @StanislavVolodarskiy, передаёт в функцию **строковый литерал**. Ну проверили вы внутри функции `newstr`, что выражение `"very_long_string" != NULL` истинно. Это никак не препятствует попытке освобождения строкового литерала `free("very_long_string");`, что есть ошибка.

Comment: @wololo Функция *newstr()* **возвращает** указатель. Значит его значение каким-то образом **вычисляется** внутри этой функции. Значит это значение надо проверь **до** оператора *return*. Нельзя возвращать недопустимое значение.  И поэтому проверка валидности должна быть **зесь**. Что-то я устал... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется по смыслу даже названия функции нужно всегда возвращать новую строку
тогда и не будет возникать вопрос - когда вызывать free();

```
char* newstr(char* str, int n)
{
  int len = strlen(str);
  char *retstr = malloc(n+1);
  
  if( len > n){
    memcpy(retstr,str+len-n,n);
  }
  else{
    memset(retstr,'*',n-len);
    memcpy(retstr+n-len,str,len);
  }
  retstr[n] = 0;
  return(retstr);
}
```